# xcode botでレポジトリサーバーの自己証明を許可する方法

Tags: xcode6

xcode botでレポジトリサーバーの自己証明を許可する方法について教えてください。

botを作成し、provide repository credential for this bot画面で、
「証明書は信頼されている必要があります」ということなので、
許可をクリックして、次に進めようとするのですが、
一度、インジケータが表示され、その後再び「証明書は信頼されている必要があります」の画面に戻り、
先に進めません。

自己証明が許可されていないということなので、

/Library/Server/Xcode/Config/xcsbuildd.plistのファイルの
TrustSelfSignedSSLCertificates keyの項をtrueに変更したり、
キーチェーンから、対象の証明書の信頼情報を「always trust」に変更ましたが
まったく問題が解決しません。

解決のアイデアがあれば、教えていただけないでしょうか？
よろしくお願いします。